# Printing as many numbers as possible in 9 seconds then a "-1" at the 10th second

Tags: python-3.x, random, numbers

So, I'm interested in printing as many numbers as possible in 9 seconds then printing a -1 at the 10th second. I have a while loop to print -1 every 10 seconds and a while loop to print any random number between 0 and 10 every 9 seconds. I am doing like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KgZe.png).

My problem is two-fold:

1. I'm not sure how to create a loop which can print as many possible numbers (depending on computing speed) in 9 seconds
2. I'm not sure how to put that together with the loop to print -1 every 10 seconds.

Thanks so much everyone!

Comment: Cheat.  Start with a string: "1 2 3 4 ... 99 100".  Print that string as many times as you can and then print -1. :)

Comment: What are you supposed to do between the 9th and 10th seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `time` module of python for this purpose. Check the below code for reference :

```
import time
import random

# Time for which you want the loop to run
time_to_run = 25
# Stores the future time when the loop should stop
loop_for_x_seconds = time.time() + time_to_run
start_time = time.time()
multiplier = 1 # print -1 at 10 second, increment it, so next one will be at 10*multiplier = 20 and so on...

# Loop until current time is less than the time we want our loop to run
while time.time() < loop_for_x_seconds:
    # The below condition will help print -1 after about every 10s
    if (time.time()-start_time)>=10*multiplier:
        print(-1)
        multiplier+=1
    # Commented below just for purpose of showing output of -1 every 10s. Uncomment and use to get random ints printed
    #else:
        #print(random.randint(1,10))
```

**Output :**

```
-1
-1
```

The above code will print `-1` after every 10 seconds approximately. I could have done `(time.time()-start_time)%10==0` ,but this condition would rarely  have been evaluated to True.

So, I went with `(time.time()-start_time)>=10*multiplier` . This code would print `-1` after every 10s elapses ( with a difference of few milliseconds ).

You don't need to use `time.sleep(10)` as you showed in the image, since that would just be like pausing the loop. However, you want to continuously run the loop printing -1 every 10s and random integers other times. So the above code would serve your purpose.

Hope this helps !